# Erlang: How can I use binary keys / data with eredis?

Tags: redis, erlang

I'm kinda new to erlang and it's been an adventure. I wanted to implement a rate limiter and came into some issues with key generation. I had tinkered with implementing the limiter a while ago... probably a year. I've wanted to clean it up a bit...

(It's a small piece in a much larger project. Now I'm taking it seriously)

I'm just going to imagine my app is successful and I'm receiving tens of thousands of requests per second. When I first wrote my code here's a snippet:

```
getClientIP(Socket) ->
    {ok, {ClientIP, _ }} = inet:peername(Socket),
    TplC = tuple_to_list(ClientIP),
    {iolist_to_binary(TplC), lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p",[TplC]))}.

makeRedisRLKeys(ClientIPStr,TimeShort,TimeLong) ->
    RKeyPrefix =  ClientIPStr ++ ":",
    {ClientIPStr, RKeyPrefix ++ integer_to_list(TimeShort) ++ ":16s", RKeyPrefix ++ integer_to_list(TimeLong) ++ ":36h"}.
```

All this code... running over and over again. I was curious if redis can store binary data. I did some searching and the answer is (suppose to be) yes.... programatically, as keys and values. So I tried it in the shell with:

```
eredis:q(R,["set",R,R]).
```

R was expanded into a 27 byte binary but it failed. I then assigned miscellaneous bytes to two variables and inserted them... same result.

I just started rewriting my limiter on the erlang side:

```
rate_limit(PartialKey) ->
    { M, S, _ } = now(),
    Time = M*1000000 + S,
    TimeLong = Time band 16#fffffffffffff000,
```

I know what is below is not syntactically correct but I'm trying to do something like:

```
BucketShort = <<ClientIP, Time>>,
BucketLong = <<ClientIP, TimeLong>>,
```

Possible?

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get any useful error information?
e.g. `eredis:q(R,["set",R,R]).` works for me assuming `R` is a valid redis connection.

Comment: Perhaps it's the version of erlang I'm using. What are you using? I followed Pascal's answer and am getting the same result as before: exception exit

Comment: I'm using Erlang R17 and Eredis 1.0.8.

Comment: Thanks... figured it out. Took me so long to respond because I kept getting errors. Wasn't doing {ok,R} = eredis:start_link() just R=... and other similar mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for eredis query is strange: `eredis:q(R,["set",R,R])`. will fails unless R is the pid of your eredis application.

The syntax for the "set" command is `eredis:q(Pid,["set",Key,Value]).` where Pid is the pid of the eredis application: `{ok, Pid} = eredis:start_link()`, Key and Value are the key/value you want to store expressed as io_list (a nested list of list and binaries).

I don't understand what you are trying to store exactly, lets say you want to store for each ClientIP 2 records, one with Time, one with TimeLong. you could achieve this with the code:

```
{ok, Pid} = eredis:start_link(),
eredis:q(Pid,["set",term_to_binary([ClientIP,short]),term_to_binary(Time)]),
eredis:q(Pid,["set",term_to_binary([ClientIP,long]),term_to_binary(TimeLong)]),
```

or if you want 1 single record:

```
eredis:q(Pid,["set",term_to_binary(ClientIP),term_to_binary([Time,TimeLong])]),
```

Comment: Thanks. That BIF is very helpful in cleaning up my code. :D R is the redis PID. That line was just a quick test. I like using atoms vs computing the times. :) But it is still not working. Exception exit. I'll update my post.

Comment: No need to. My mistakes. Works like a charm. Thank you.